# ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC : DirectoryNotFoundException While trying to download the file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0, aspnetcore-environment

I am trying to get a file name from database, attach a proper path to it and get it downloaded on my system. Unfortunately I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

The button I click Is : "Download Id Proof"

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\images\Apply\POfId\10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg'.
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)

Here is my view markup:

```
@model Derawala.Models.ViewModels.ParentForApply
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<h1>Details</h1>
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Apply.PofId" hidden />
    <div class="container backgroundWhite pt-4">
        <div class="card" style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
            @*<div class="card-header bg-dark text-light ml-0 row container" style="border-radius: 0px;">*@
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color:black;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-start">
                        <h1 class="text-white">@Model.Apply.FirstName&nbsp;@Model.Apply.LastName</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-end">
                        <h1 class="text-warning">Application Id :@Model.Apply.AppId</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container rounded p-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 p-1 text-center">
                            <img src="@WC.ImagePath[0]@Model.Apply.Photo" class="rounded w-25" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                            <div class="row pl-3">

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <span class="badge p-3 border" style="background-color:lightpink">@Model.Apply.Qualification</span>
                                    <span class="badge p-3 border" style="background-color:lightskyblue">@Model.Apply.SchType</span>
                                    <h3 class="text-success"></h3>

                                    <p class="text-secondary">@Model.Apply.Description</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row pl-3">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    Download Id Proof : <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model.Apply.PofId" asp-action="DownloadFile">Download</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-dark">
                <div class="row">
                   
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
                        
                    <a asp-action="RemoveFromCart" class="btn btn-primary btn-square form-control btn-lg" style="height:50px;">Donate Now <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-medical"></i></a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control btn-lg" style="height:50px;">Delete This Application <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here this is the code for the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string id)
{
        string DirPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var objdata = _db.Apply.Where(i => i.PofId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        string FileName = objdata.PofId;
        var FilePath = Path.Combine(DirPath,WC.ImagePath[1], FileName);
        var memory = new MemoryStream();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(FilePath,FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }

        memory.Position = 0;
        var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
        return File(memory, contentType, FileName);
}
```

[You can see the error in detail in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2pNk.png)

[You can also see that the image and the path actually exist in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M6e5.png)

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi, what is your value of `WC.ImagePath[1]` and `FileName`? Be sure the value should be like below: `var FilePath = Path.Combine(DirPath, "images/Apply/POfId", "10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg");`.

Comment: Hi @Rena
Yes the values are correct. WC.ImagePath[1] has the value "\\images\\Apply\\POfId" and FileName has the value  "10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg"

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi, please debug your code and check what is the value of `DirPath `. Your error message `D:\images\Apply\POfId\10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg` here seems not bind absolute location of  `wwwroot`. The correct location should be `ProjectLocation/wwwroot/ImageLocation` by default. Where did your 10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg' locate in? Does it in wwwroot folder? If not, how did you configure this static file?

Comment: @Rena You can see that the image is in wwwroot folder in the second Screenshot image which I have shared above

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi, so what is the value of DirPath? Your error message here `D:\images\Apply\POfId\10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg` does not contain the project location. I mean where do you create the project?

Comment: hi @Rena Here is project path : D:\ASP.Net Core Projects\Derawala

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi, I mean, did you debug your code and check the `DirPath` if it equals to your `D:\ASP.Net Core Projects\Derawala`? Also the `FilePath` should be: `D:\ASP.Net Core Projects\Derawala\images\Apply\POfId\10157d06-bf72-4ea1-b316-b22ac5feae20.jpg`. Please debug your code to check if they are correct or not .

Comment: Hi @Rena Yes I have debugged the project the path is the same as u wrote above. Actually it was Path.Combine which broke my path every time. So I removed the Path.Combine and now it works just fine. :). By the way thanks a lot for helping me looking into it. :)